# Add react-router-dom Link in ag-grid react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, ag-grid-react

How can I replace a  with   of react-router-dom, in ag-grid. It is making the page reload instead of pretending to be a single page application.

I have tried with this but it doesn't work

```
cellRenderer:  (params)=> {
  return <Link to={`/?info=${params.data.Id}`}>"+{params.value}+"</Link>,
```

Is there a possibility that we can use Link instead of

```
cellRenderer:  function(params){
  return "<a href='/?info=" + params.data.Id+ "'>"+params.value+"</a>";},
```

when using Link it is throwing the Error:

> Error: ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle
>   of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the
>   grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into
>   a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call
>   setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your
>   code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

The error in stacktrace points to the code below, But with  element it works fine:

> ===> GetAPI(){ var url = xxxxxxxxxxx; axios.get(url).then(response => { if (response.status == 200) { this.setState({ patients:
>   response.data, loading: false }); } }) .catch(e => console.log('Error
>   While Fetching Fee List: at Listing/index.js > Error: ', e.message,'\n
>   for user : ',this.props.auth.user.email)) }.

Comment: when using `Link` is it throwing any error.

Comment: and when you `anchor` tag it will reload the page which is a default and expected behavior

Comment: when using Link it is throwing the Error:                                                   Error: ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. Can you make stackblitz of some part of your code, so that I can fix it for you?

Comment: I can't share my piece of code, but the error in stacktrace points to the   code below, But with <a> element it works fine  ===>  GetAPI(){
        var url = `xxxxxxxxxxx`;
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                this.setState({ patients: response.data, loading: false });
            }
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('Error While Fetching Fee List: at Listing/index.js > Error: ', e.message,'\n for user : ',this.props.auth.user.email))
    }.

Comment: What is gridAPI's refreashView()?  Where do I need to call it? Do I need to call it after getting the data from the server and updating the state. It don't give any error with html <a/>. Why It need to refresh when we use <Link/>

Comment: try: `cellRenderer:  (params)=> {
  return <Link to={'/?info=' + params.data.Id}>{params.value}</Link>` to see what happens. Also, which version of react router are you using?

Comment: Tried cellRenderer: (params)=> { return <Link to={'/?info=' + params.data.Id}>{params.value}</Link>, but it is throwing the same error. @c-chavez

Comment: having the same problem here. The ag-grid error is a result of an error thrown by the Link component: `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`. I haven't figured out how to get the link working though, as the ag-grid is inside a <Router>

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon this solution out of dumb luck but if you add `reactNext={true}` as a prop to AgGridReact, your first  solution will work with cellRendererFramework.

```
      <AgGridReact
        reactNext={true}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowData={tableData}
      >
      </AgGridReact>
```

Then in your columnDefs object add this attribute,

```
cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
  return <Link to={`/?info=${params.data.Id}`}>"+{params.value}+"</Link>,
```

Apparently in the Ag grid documentation, they said features included in reactNext will eventually be merged into the stable source code, but it hasn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced similar issue. The way I solved it was by handling Cell Clicked Event. Inside Cell Clicked Event I checked which column it is coming from and did `props.history.push`.

```
onCellClicked: (events) => {
    if(events && events.column && events.column.colDef.field === "accountId") {
        props.history.push(`/${events.value}`);
    }
}
```